# How to show JavaScript code on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

How to show the following Javascript code, but not run it?

```
<script>alert("test");</script>
```

I tried to show this code on my page, but when user loads the page it alerts "test".

How can I show the code but not run it on page load?

Comment: use `&lt;script&gt;alert("test");&lt;/script&gt;`

Comment: Depending on your server-side scripting language, you should have an automatic method to replace HTML special characters as `<` with their HTML entity equivalent as `&lt;`. For example, in PHP you can use `htmlspecialchars()` to accomplish this.

Comment: @robert devverlo  see i updated my answer , i know you got solution but i corrected my answer so if some one come and see answer then correct answer will help that persone

Answer (score 2):

Use `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`

```html
<code>
    &lt;script&gt;alert("test");&lt;/script&gt;
</code>
```

Comment: i updated my answer so  now it is correct or not using jquery i given one solution please let me know if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

```html
<pre><code>&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;
 </code></pre>
```

---

**OR**

Using **Jquery** you can simply add text  on particular selector using **.text()**

Jquery example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.showText').text("<script>alert('text')<"+"/script>");
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="showText"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!-- Sadly (totally)... this is obsolete :( -->
<xmp>
<script>alert("test");</script>
</xmp>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#xmp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/plaintext
**https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/PlaintextElement**
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/x/xmp.htm
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/p/plaintext.htm

;) Great stuff but **sadly** you're on the browser's mercy since `<plaintext>` and `<xmp>` are obsolete,
so 
escaping the `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;` (or with hex `&#60;`, `&#62;`)
is a far better idea.

```html
&lt;script&gt;alert("test");&lt;/script&gt;
```

You can wrap the above for **semantic reasons** in tags like `<pre>` or `<code>` although it's not needed to achieve the desired.
So the point is that we're over and over suggested to use `<pre>`, yet we still miss a proper and valid tag to literalize and represent `<`, `&`, `>` without escaping.